# Multiple language data field in Acumatica Report Designer

Tags: acumatica

I want to use this Inventory Item multiple language in report designer
[translations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj7zd.png)

This field in InvenrotyItemKvExt DAC but I can find it in Report Designer [report designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czgmm.png)

Can you guy help me find this field, thanks so much !

Answer (score 0):

Acumatica will replace the description field of InventoryItem by the desired locale so you don't have to directly work with InventoryItemKvExt table.

When you launch a report you can specify the locale:
[image]

You can provide a default locale in the report editor or use a custom formula to select the locale:
[image]

In the report, the 'InventoryItem.Descr' field value will be translated to the report locale:
[image]

You can refer to this Acumatica help page for additional information: [Translating Reports](https://help.acumatica.com/Wiki/Show.aspx?pageid=10c0a76d-0bb5-47dd-89b3-2e4c16c5c073)